# How to keep image synced?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, picasso, android-glide

How can I keep an image synced and not downloaded again and again, so when I scroll down it disappears, when I scroll up it downloads it again,
or if I close the app and open it again it will keep the images.

This is my firebase alwaysSync

```
public class Firebase_sync extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if(!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()){
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }
        Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
        builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this,Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        Picasso built = builder.build();
        built.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
        built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);



    }
}
```

I tried Picasso And Glide!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're using an Application subclass to display an image, I'm assuming that's a typo since that's not really possible, so I'll assume you're using an activity. To save the image from loading more than once, add this to your Manifest XML file in the activity that has the image:

```
android:launchMode = "singleInstance"
```

Or if it's in a Fragment, write this in the onCreate method of the fragment:

```
this.setRetainInstance(true);
```